# Adding localized files to a new IOS 7 app

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm starting to studying app localizations and I'm stuck at the very beginning.. I've created a new project called *LocalizedStrings2*:

[image: new project settings]

I click the plus button to add *Italian Language* and it offers me to localize 2 InfoPlist.strings files:

[image: add italian localization]

Is this correct? BTW, I add the italian language:

[image: two InfoPlist.strings files]

Then I've wrote the following code in the English InfoPlist.strings file:

```
"ERR_MSG" = "Error Message!"
```

The following line has been entered in the Italian version of the file:

```
"ERR_MSG" = "Messaggio d'errore!"
```

When I compile I receive the following error (I have the same error even if the two files are empty:

[image: Error message]

Any hint or good reference for up-to-date *How To Localize my IOS App* documentation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gianni

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem for many days. Then I figured it out…
Just put a ; at the end of the line and it's fixed! :D

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation**

I don't think you should have two English references to your file in the UI. Change one to italian and verify that the files are in the proper location in your finder folder.

I would then consider removing the file references from the project and re-add them. I've noticed some peculiar behaviors when using localization for older versions of the SDK in Xcode 5+. BTW - If you are planning to support a deployment target of iOS5 you will need to remove the Base localization setting and just create the localization folders manually (inside the project folder in Finder). After you re-add the files I would check the Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources > search for plist to verify that ProjectName/(localization).lproj is found.

**NOTE**
Please check out the updated documentation and let me know if that is a sufficient answer.

[Internationalizing Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html)

Comment: I'll surely read it... but why do I see two *InfoPlist.strings* files when I add a new language to the project? Why does it produce a compile error even without manipulating anything else after adding the new language?

Comment: @GianniCostanzi - Compile error is probably due to not changing the target language to something other than English (as in the image above, English is selected twice). Try the updated suggestion in my answer to see if it helps or refine the problem further if the issue continues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second InfoPlist.strings file derives trom your tests.
Check out the "Supporting Files-Folder" in your apps test target.